# Matrix-Trace and Conjugate Transpose (Multiple Choice)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

I was trying to solve the following problem from a competitive exam paper.

Let $A=( a_{ij})$ be a nXn complex matrix and let $A^*$ denote the conjugate transpose of $A$. Then which of the following statements are necessarily true? (One or more options may be correct)

1. $A^{-1}$ exists $\Rightarrow tr(A^*A)\neq 0 $
2. $ tr(A^*A)\neq 0 \Rightarrow A^{-1} $ exists.
3. $|tr(A^*A)|<n^2\Rightarrow | a_{ij}|<1 $ for some $i,j$
4. $ tr(A^*A)= 0 \Rightarrow A = 0$

I am completely stuck.

Please help me.
Thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only 2 is false. You can easily decide on all four by using
$$
\text{Tr}(A^*A)=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n|A_{kj}|^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have a little doubt. Can you please clarify how option 3 is coming out to be true from your given formula?

Comment: If $|A_{kj}|\geq1$ for all $k,j$, then adding $n^2$ of those numbers will be at least $n^2$.

Comment: Thank you again.It is very much clear now.